# Running rails server in production mode locally times out on API request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, thin

I'm trying to run the Thin server locally in production mode. It work fine in development mode, but in production mode when I make a request it just times out. Why so?

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
AnthemsController here
/Users/etayluz/Anthem-API/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant MANDRILL_APIKEY
/Users/etayluz/Anthem-API/config/environments/production.rb:74: warning: previous definition of MANDRILL_APIKEY was here
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms state=ready
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=2ms state=active
Started POST "/register.json" for 192.168.0.13 at 2015-02-26 00:02:05 -0500
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=1001ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=2003ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=3003ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=4001ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=5001ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=6005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=d7eaf46f126de85f12a78924e1c12c49 timeout=30000ms service=30000ms state=timed_out
```